# Which Table Holds FK Constraint In One to One Relationship

Tags: mysql, database

Which table host the FK when there is a One-to-One relationship between two table? For example when having a relationship like this should I put the FK in `author` or `books` tables?

[image]

Comment: A one-to-one-relationship here would mean that an author can only write a single book.

Comment: Thanks for reply, in my spacific case this is Ok but what i need to care about is, if a book deleted the authr should be still there but an author deleted the book also must be deleted

Comment: Do you know about [ON DELETE CASCADE](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-on-delete-cascade/) ?

Comment: I guess my question is very clear. I a one to many relationship the child entity holds the FK constraints. Now in one to one relationship which one hold it?

Comment: In practive - clear one-to-one cannot exist (if create such relation type none data can be inserted because of violation by another table). It may be one-to-(zero-or-one). And this relation type is implemented as UNIQUE KEY in one table and FOREIGN KEY + UNIQUE KEY in another.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the foreign key on the `books` table.

Reasoning: An author may live before they write their first book, but a book cannot exist without first having an author.

This means a row can exist in your `author` table with no corresponding row in your `books` table, but the reverse cannot be true.